# Formula in Crystal report doesn't work

Tags: crystal-reports

I have below formula in my crystal report which doesn't work.

```
if({SINGLECASEMULTIPLEASSAY.sSampleName}="P")then
val({SINGLECASEMULTIPLEASSAY.sODValue})
```

The output of the formula field is always 0.00 although the table SINGLECASEMULTIPLEASSAY has correct values. I also verified that table SINGLECASEMULTIPLEASSAY has valid data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `VAL()` function returns a numeric based on what text you are inputting.

If you are inputting text with no numbers in, this will return 0.00

If you inserted `Val("2234 100th Street")` you would get the result `2234100` - taken from IBM's webpage [here.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic645.html)

Check the values in the field *{SINGLECASEMULTIPLEASSAY.sODValue}* and see if they contain any numbers; if they do make sure they are not prefixed by any spaces or letters.

If you are simply trying to display *{SINGLECASEMULTIPLEASSAY.sODValue}* then you do not need the `VAL()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You ALWAYS need to test for null values in Crystal Reports first:

```
If Isnull({SINGLECASEMULTIPLEASSAY.sSampleName}) Then
  0
Else If {SINGLECASEMULTIPLEASSAY.sSampleName}="P" Then
  ToNumber({SINGLECASEMULTIPLEASSAY.sODValue})
```