# Excluded non-numeric from Crystal Report Average Convert to Percent

Tags: crystal-reports, average

How do I exclude the text (**-Very Courteous**) from the value, for example (**4-Very Courteous**)  to do average by tech?

Can I add average by tech to this formula?

**{vwsvAllSurveyResponses.DateCompleted} = {?Date Survey Completed} and
{vwsvAllSurveyResponses.Name} = {?Select Survey}**

I am unable to upload example. . .

===================
January 13, 2012

thanks. This is the final formula. Val(ToText(-Val({vwsvAllSurveyResponses.Response})))

I was able to get the averages. I am trying to convert the Average to percent? Avg of @Actual Value(number)*

I get an error that the field name does not exist: {Avg of @Actual Value} /4 * 100

Answer (score 0):

If your text field is always prefixed by a number; the formula `Val()` will help you.

Val returns the starting numbers in a string as an integer.

[See this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260724/formula-in-crystal-report-doesnt-work/8262828#8262828)

You should then be able to produce your averages.

Selecting which averages to display is harder.  You could suppress results where the average does not meet your parameters. So on each display line have a conditional suppress statement to only show averages in a certain range. I think you may also be able to add averages in the selection formula.  I do not have crystal here to test this though!

Comment: Hi, thank you. It was not clear to me where to enter the Val() {vwsvAllSurveyResponses.DateCompleted} = {?Date Survey Completed} and {vwsvAllSurveyResponses.Name} = {?Select Survey}

Comment: From the names of the fields you have provided; it is not obvious which one you need to use it on. You need to use it on the field that gives you the text "4 - Very Courteous".  Val("4 - Very Courteous") will give you the integer 4 as a result.